# Visualforce in safelorce app (or salesforce1 app) mobile redirect to browser phone

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have a Visualforce that creates a quote in Salesforce app and after the quote is  saved I want redirect to the quote's detail page in the app, but it is sending me automatically to my phone's browser.

In the Visualforce I'm using the next:

```
PageReference oPageRef = new PageReference('/'+quoteToCreate.id);
oPageRef.setRedirect(false);
```

Does it have something to do with my code? What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

For Salesforce Apps, you would need to use the sforce object as defined in the [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_pages_multipurpose.htm)

> For pages shared between the Salesforce app and the full Salesforce site, you’ll want to write code that uses the sforce object when it’s available, and standard Visualforce navigation when it’s not.

Example from the docs:

```
// Go back to the Account detail page
if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && sforce && (!!sforce.one) ) {
    // Salesforce app navigation
    sforce.one.navigateToSObject(aId);
}
else {
    // Set the window's URL using a Visualforce expression
    window.location.href = 
        '{!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, account.Id)}';
}
```